# How to reload a Visual Studio extension when debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm new to building Visual Studio extensions, I'm trying to debug my extension but whenever I modify anything on the source I need to:

uninstall the extension -> close vs -> install the new compiled extension -> reopen

This process is so tedious is it the correct way of debugging an extension when you modify the source?

Comment: When I created an extension, I could run it in an "[Experimental Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2022)" of VS

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i didnt understand how to launch the Experimental Instance, also do you still need to uninstall the extension and install again whenever you modify it source?

Comment: It's been a while but IIRC a startup project was added that launched that special VS instance and updated the extension with the latest code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to get the extension using the modified source without needing to reinstall it, for it I need to start the VS instance as a "**experimental instance**" by adding the command `/rootsuffix Exp` on `Start options`:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 0):

Which version of your Visual Studio?
Debugging a Visual Studio extension can be done by using the Hot Reload feature, which allows you to edit your code and apply the changes to the running application without restarting it. This can save you a lot of time and hassle.

Comment: VS22, when I modify anything in the extension source I get this message: https://i.imgur.com/GpkbZod.png, and the new code doesn't get into effect until I reinstall the extension :(

Comment: Just to add the link to the feature [here] (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/)

Answer (score 0):

This case is solved by:

1. Right click the project
2. Choose Open Folder in File Explorer
3. Open packages.config
4. Edit version Extension or delete it if not in use.

Comment: Hi, see my comment below.